# low cpu usage when I run a simple cnn model on jupyter notebook

Tags: performance, machine-learning, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, cpu-usage

I run a very simple CNN model on the Jupyter notebook, but the process is very slow. I run the same program on my old laptop(core i7U 10gen). and it just took one and half minutes, but on my new laptop(core i9 13900hx and rtx4060) it took 30 minutes!!! They are both ran on CPU, but on my old PC, the CPU usage is 100%, on my new PC, it is about 20%. And then, I run the same program in the PyCharm, it's normal! This confused me very much, I have tried many ways but don't work. I wanna wonder where the real problem is? My Jupyter notebook or other thing?

I tried run the same program on different PC, on different IDE platform. I wanna wonder where the real problem is.

Comment: How about GPU usage?

Comment: almost 0@Raptor

Comment: There is no code here, you need to include it, else you will have people guessing the problem.

Comment: Although it's just a small model, but the code is still long. And actually I don't think it's a code problem at first so I don't include it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you're experiencing could be related to the configuration of Jupyter Notebook and how it utilizes resources. You can do following suggestions to potentially improve the performance.

1. Check Jupyter Notebook Configuration

Ensure that Jupyter Notebook is using the correct Python kernel. Sometimes, Jupyter Notebook may use a different Python environment than the one you intend to use.

2. Check Resource Allocation

Check the resource allocation for Jupyter Notebook by running the following commands in a Jupyter Notebook cell. Ensure that Jupyter is using all available CPU cores. If not you can adjust.

```
import os
os.cpu_count()
```

3. Update Jupyter and Dependencies

You can update them using the following commands.

```
!pip install --upgrade jupyter
!pip install --upgrade numpy tensorflow
```

4. Use Jupyter Extensions

You can install Jupyter Extenstions like

- jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
- nbresuse

to monitor resource usage and manage the notebook environment.

Answer (score 0):

I tried another way to speed the process.
Firstly, I run the following code to find the best parameter of num_workers.

```
from time import time
import multiprocessing as mp
import torch
import torchvision
from torchvision import transforms
 
 
transform = transforms.Compose([
    torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
    torchvision.transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))
])
 
trainset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(
    root='dataset/',
    train=True,  #如果为True，从 training.pt 创建数据，否则从 test.pt 创建数据。
    download=True, #如果为true，则从 Internet 下载数据集并将其放在根目录中。 如果已下载数据集，则不会再次下载。
    transform=transform
)
 
print(f"num of CPU: {mp.cpu_count()}")
for num_workers in range(2, mp.cpu_count(), 2):  
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, shuffle=True, num_workers=num_workers, batch_size=64, pin_memory=True)
    start = time()
    for epoch in range(1, 3):
        for i, data in enumerate(train_loader, 0):
            pass
    end = time()
    print("Finish with:{} second, num_workers={}".format(end - start, num_workers))
```

here are the output:

```
num of CPU: 32
Finish with:8.80056643486023 second, num_workers=2
Finish with:6.9174275398254395 second, num_workers=4
Finish with:6.977447032928467 second, num_workers=6
Finish with:6.9256751537323 second, num_workers=8
Finish with:7.585498094558716 second, num_workers=10
Finish with:8.303900718688965 second, num_workers=12
Finish with:9.681997299194336 second, num_workers=14
Finish with:10.215168476104736 second, num_workers=16
Finish with:10.819851875305176 second, num_workers=18
Finish with:11.382972717285156 second, num_workers=20
Finish with:12.100224256515503 second, num_workers=22
Finish with:12.827118635177612 second, num_workers=24
Finish with:13.584873914718628 second, num_workers=26
Finish with:14.99898624420166 second, num_workers=28
Finish with:15.615322828292847 second, num_workers=30
```

the previous value of num_workers is 2 and I changed it to 8. After that, I surprisely found that did work! It ran much more faster.Here is what I changed:

```
trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True,
                                        download=True, transform=transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=4,
                                          shuffle=True, num_workers=8)
```

Although the superficial problems is solved, but I am still confused that why the same program run normally on my old pc and pycharm but don't work on my new pc's jupyter notebook. I suppose that is a problem about cpu schedule, it's just a guess cause I'm not expert on this. Someone who know this can tell me about that?